# Unable to refer another spreadsheet value using INDIRECT in Google Sheet inside regexmatch

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, importrange

I want to highlight rows of Sheet-1 whose column C has similar values of sheet-2 column 'A'. I have tried using the following expression one by one on custom formula through Format-conditional formatting. but none of them are giving the result as expected.

```
=REGEXMATCH($C2, INDIRECT("disposable-emails!A1"))
=FILTER(C2, COUNTIF(INDIRECT("disposable-emails!A1:A"),C2))
=FILTER(C2, COUNTIF(INDIRECT("disposable-emails!A1:A"),"*"&C2&"*"))
=REGEXMATCH(C2, TEXTJOIN("|",1,INDIRECT("disposable-emails!A1:A")))
```

and Unfortunately, this also didn't worked:

```
=IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDIRECT("'disposable-emails'!A1:A"))))<>"",1)
```

[image: Click here to see the image]

So I am sharing you both sheet link these are editable:

Sheet-2: disposable-emails

[Click here to see Sheet-2 disposable-emails](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16KZ35pdpQ_iTWAvUoz0phyKz3TzOQzTEbOU9NHTcjTQ/edit#gid=0)

Sheet-1: WebMessages

[Click here to see Sheet-1 webmessages](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19gwTMmHWyYdUacibps7Bk68ouwPxX7ItpwNVQhVXSK8/edit#gid=0)

IMPORTANT: I want the entire row to be highlighted based on matching column value (not only the column cell but the entire row of that cell).

Apart from my main query, there is another formatting rule that is, if a bot-state column has any value (not blank) then highlight that entire row (not only the column cell but the entire row of that cell). You have to select the bot-state column to see 2nd rule

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with `INDIRECT` function if you have 2 separate spreadsheets. merge your Sheet1 and Sheet2 **under one spreadsheet** and do:

```
=IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 INDIRECT("'disposable-emails'!A1:A"))))<>"",1)
```

[image: 0]

### **[spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N8BzC-UlOktUnHNsfLYlihBUE1ViSSmXZEG8BLbmbKM/edit#gid=1506350403)**

Comment: but previously you shared me an example where your expression is working on your sheet. So that is why I shared my sheet to you thinking that you will see and tell me why it is not happening with my sheets. And I believe it is basic functionality to compare other sheet value and if matching with the first sheet then highlight these record. Then why you are suggesting me to include records of sheet 2 in sheet 1. Please provide me any expression or any way where we can achieve this basic functionality. If I am misunderstanding the term merge then please provide me how to merge these two sheets.

Comment: I will be very thankful to you, It is important for me and it is basic functionality in the database and I believe it is possible in google sheet also.

Comment: see your sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19gwTMmHWyYdUacibps7Bk68ouwPxX7ItpwNVQhVXSK8/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi Player0, I am observing a strange phenomenon that the expression you gave me, it is working for that previous value only but if i am inserting new values in the other sheet it is not comparing from new values. see here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aChE5KEQnIVcC2itUFlfZK66TXBAFAwbhV4pE2uzwA4/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19gwTMmHWyYdUacibps7Bk68ouwPxX7ItpwNVQhVXSK8/edit?usp=sharing